# jQuery using checkboxes to hide/show content

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 6 different checkboxes (example of one):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="navigationItem" onclick="showChapter(this)" value="1" checked="checked" >1
```

I have 6 different chapters (example of one):

```
<div id="chapter1"> </div>
```

And i need to write a simple jQuery to show/hide chapters depending on selected checkboxes.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.navigationItem').is(':checked')){
        $($("chapter") + $('.navigationItem').val()).show();
    } else {
        $($("chapter") + $('.navigationItem').val()).hide();
    }
});
```

However this does not work I have also tried to do it like this:

```
function showChapter(cb){
var x = cb.value;            
        if($('.navigationItem').is(':checked')){
            $("chapter"+x).show();
        } else {
            $("chapter"+x).hide();
        }            
}
```

But this also does not work. I just started learning JavaScript and jQuery and any help to point me into the right direction would be very appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: For one, your selectors are not right, what is `"chapter"+x`, the ID of the element? Then it should be `"#chapter"+x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can get rid of `onclick="showChapter(this)"`. You'll just need this:

```
$('.navigationItem').on('change', function() {
    var dv = $('#chapter' + $(this).val());
    $(this).is(':checked') ? dv.show() : dv.hide();
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/06r7cwfn/)

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. I kinda understand everything just what is $(this).is(':checked') ? dv.show() : dv.hide(); is it like shortened if statment? $(this).is(':checked') gives false.true and then mark '?' is then and ':' else?

Comment: Exactly! It's a shorthand for `if($(this).is(':checked')) dv.show(); else dv.hide();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".navigationItem").change(function(e) {
  var chapter = $(this).val();
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#chapter"+chapter).show();
  } else {
    $("#chapter"+chapter).hide();
  }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Ok I just need a little clarification    
1. $(".navigationItem").change   
this line activates whenever there is change in the checkbox (select/unselect) right?  
  
2. Why is it function(e) what does that e do?

Comment: Yes, it will catch the select and unselect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navigationItem')
```

returns an array of objects, so to select one object you have to do:

```
$('.navigationItem').get( 0 ); //or the index you want
```

Use the same logic with  elements instead of select them by id, it's easier